# Hot Reload not working after upgrading .net 5.0 to .net 6.0

Tags: .net, blazor-webassembly

I have converted .net framework 5.0 to framework 6.0.It works fine without any error or bugs.
there is a feature in .net 6.0 (Hot Reload) is not working after upgrading .net 5.0 to 6.0.

Note:-
I am using .net 6.0 Blazor Web Assembly

[Hot Reload Visual Studio 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHA86.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using VisualStudio22 ? Otherwise Hot reload wont work.
Also check VisualStudio settings if Hot Reload is enabled.

Click the **Fire** icon right after **Start without debugging** button, then go to **Settings** > **Debugging** > **.Net/C++ Hot Reload** and check if all of the checkboxes are enabled.

Comment: I have change but still not working.see the attached image for your referernce

Comment: Did you try starting without Debugging and check if it is working ?

Comment: yes,but still not working